# Keep some groups from GroupBy using list of indices

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hello StackOverflowers!

I have a pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1,1,2,1,3,3,1,6,3,5,1],
    'B':[10,10,300,10,30,40,20,10,30,45,20],
    'C':[20,20,20,20,15,20,15,15,15,15,15],
    'D':[10,20,30,40,80,10,20,50,30,10,70],
    'E':[10,10,10,22,22,3,4,5,9,0,1]
})
```

Then I groupby it on some columns

```
groups = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I would like to select/filter the original data based on the groupby indices.

For example I would like to get 3 random combinations out of the groupby

Any ideas?

Comment: could u explain what u mean by groupby indices? indices of each group? the answer u provided below has indices pre allocated, and not necessarily pulled from any of the groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of iterating along all groups `len(indices)` times and indexing on the respective  `indices` value each time, get a list of the groups' `keys` from the dictionary returned by [`GroupBy.groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html), and do single calls to [`GroupBy.get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html) for each index:

```
keys = list(groups.groups.keys())
# [(1, 10, 20), (1, 20, 15), (2, 300, 20)...
pd.concat([groups.get_group(keys[i]) for i in indices])

    A   B   C   D   E
6   1  20  15  20   4
10  1  20  15  70   1
5   3  40  20  10   3
4   3  30  15  80  22
8   3  30  15  30   9
```

Comment: that looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

What I could do is

```
groups = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])

indices = [1, 4, 3]
pd.concat([[df_group for names, df_group in groups][i] for i in indices])
```

Which results to :

```
Out[24]: 
    A   B   C   D   E
6   1  20  15  20   4
10  1  20  15  70   1
5   3  40  20  10   3
4   3  30  15  80  22
8   3  30  15  30   9
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way, maybe implemented already in the pd.groupby()?